# Can I use LiHV batteries as normal batteries?

Tags: lipo-batteries, battery-safety, lihv-batteries

I have a small drone and the only batteries I can find that fit it are LiHV batteries. Can I use LiHV batteries like normal LiPo batteries? Can I just simply charge a LiHV battery to 4.2v and fly with it?

Comment: If you're satisfied with the answer I gave, please accept it.

Comment: Sorry, I just forgot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can. The primary difference between LiHV and LiPo batteries is [the ability to change them to ~4.35 V/cell](https://oscarliang.com/lihv-lipo-drone-battery-hvli/) instead of 4.20 V/cell with a [nominal cell voltage of 3.8 V](https://www.radiocontrolinfo.com/are-high-voltage-lipo-lihv-batteries-worth-it/) instead of 3.7 V.

Just like how there's nothing stopping you from only charging your LiPos to 4.1 V/cell instead of their rated full charge @ 4.20 V/cell, there's nothing wrong with charging LiHVs to a "full" charge below their rating.

Comment: Interestingly enough, it seems that LiHV packs will degrade faster than ordinary lipos even if you charge them only to 4.20V.

Comment: Yes, they use a different chemistry than LiPo cells.

Comment: Also, remember that if you don't charge them to 4.35V (full charge), then the rated capacity will be significantly lower as well.